# Static data and postgresql

Tags: postgresql, static

Does it make sense to save ~500k rows of data in a static postgresql database? I have all this information that needs to be queried as baseobject for a game I'm coding. I have a main database containing data regarding accounts/characters and so forth - and my plan is store all static information such as maps/items in a separate static database. Is my logic flawed?

Comment: It is difficult to say whether this is a good strategy without knowing what are the patterns of access you are planning and whether it is worth the trouble maintaining and running a PostgreSQL server on the destination machine. If it is SQL syntax you want, SQLite makes for a much better embedded database. What alternatives do you have? And, as an aside, this question may not be the best fit for SO (i.e. requesting recommendations on tools).

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by a "separate static database"?

Comment: Also depends on memory on devices you'd be running these. If you can load the whole data in memory, then speed and accessibility and responsiveness would be an order of magnitude faster than otherwise. Such speed will open up to a whole another level of apps. It really depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why would you use a separate DB? It means you need a separate connection pool, which is a pain. What's the advantage you see from doing so?

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is not to deal with loads of xml files "queries" - and rather to sql queries. As mentioned, the data is static - so I thought separation would be a nice way to go.